# 8 × 8 checkerboard - B/W. In how many ways can you color the checkerboard if exactly one row is entirely unicolor?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

The squares of a 8 × 8 checkerboard are colored black or white. In how many ways can you color the checkerboard if **exactly one row is entirely unicolor**?

Comment: It might help us help you if you could edit into your question what you have tried so far and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $8$ choices to choose a row that is unicolor, and $2$ choices of the color that row is going to be. For the rest of the $7$ rows, each square in that row has $2$ choices each, and there are $8$ squares in a row for a total of $2^8$, but you have to subtract $2$ to take out the cases where that row is unicolor(or else you will have more than one unicolor row), so it is actually $2^8-2$. So the final answer is $8\cdot2\cdot(2^8-2)^7=1091329761618950144$ ways.

Comment: Isn't it $(2^8 - 2)$ because we remove all the options for the line being all black *or* white?  Asking out of curiosity..

Comment: @WATER yes, that's what struck me too! Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Oh thanks for the fix! Editing right now.

Comment: Also I am confused on whether to multiply 7 with (2^8 - 2) or power it like (2^8 - 2)^7

Comment: @MaulikPipaliyaJoyy You are right, it should be $8\cdot2\cdot(2^8-2)^7$.